# How do I prevent a Loader from changing my apps position and size?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I load an SWF using a simple loader but it changes the main applications x/y position and size.

Which loader do I use to load an swf that will maintain the position size of my app?

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, function handleInit(event:Event):void{
    var UIDesigner:UIComponent = new  UIComponent();
    UIDesigner.addChild(event.target.loader.content);
    UIDesigner.id = "id_sample";
    ApplicationObject.Instance.addElementAt(UIDesigner,0)

    event.target.content.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, function applicationCompleteHandler(event:Event):void{
        var app:SystemManager = event.target as SystemManager;
        var Designer:SkinnableContainer = app.application as SkinnableContainer;
        Designer.id = "id_test";
        ApplicationObject.Instance.removeElementAt(0);
        pTabCon.addChild(Designer as SkinnableContainer);
        pTabCon.horizontalScrollPolicy = "off";
        pTabCon.verticalScrollPolicy = "off";
        Parent.id_ComponentsTab.addChild(pTabCon);
        Parent.id_ComponentsTab.selectedChild = pTabCon;
        trace("swf loaded successfully");
        ApplicationObject.Instance.m_ApplicationList.addItem(Designer);
    });                         
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the Loader but how you use it and specifically, how you add the content to the stage.

A DisplayObjectContainer will change size according to its content. For instance , if you load a MovieClip with a width of 400 in another MovieClip with a 200 width, the containing MovieClip width will change to 400. This is an expected behavior.

It's possible to modify this behavior by using masking for instance or modifying the loaded content properties before adding content to the stage.

As for the x & y properties, it would have to do with your code. Loading content shouldn't change the x & y properties of the containing Object.

If you edit your question and add some code example we may be able to give you more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

does the swf that you load call root or maybe stage? i've had such issue with an swf animated background for my app.
and how do load it?

upd: you can always use [NO_SCALE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html#NO_SCALE)

Answer (score 0):

```
    loadSWFFile("resources/awords/myswf.swf");
private function loadSWFFile(fileURL:String):void
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleSWFLoadComplete0);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler0);
    loader.load( new URLRequest(fileURL));
}
private function handleSWFLoadComplete0( evt:Event ):void
{
    loaderWidth = evt.currentTarget.loader.width;
    loaderHeight = evt.currentTarget.loader.height;

    // Now set the width and height of target component same as loaderWidth and loaderHeight respectively.
}
private function ioErrorHandler0(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    mx.controls.Alert.show("Unable to load", "IOError", 0);
}
```